# Error running NodeFuzz

Tags: fuzzing

I have been trying to fuzz chromium with NodeFuzz. I have followed this website http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/nbnfioulu-201504161396.pdf . Here is my error

```
   Loading default configuration-file:
./config.js
config.js had no property init.
Loading default instrumentation-module:
./Instrumentation.js
No module folder given. Defaulting to ./TestCaseGenerator.js from config.js
Found property init() from module ./TestCaseGenerator.js
Successfully required module ./TestCaseGenerator.js
We have 1 modules available.
Server listening port 1000
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn chromium ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
BreslinD:nodefuzz Student$ sudo node nodefuzz.js
Loading default configuration-file:
./config.js
config.js had no property init.
Loading default instrumentation-module:
./Instrumentation.js
No module folder given. Defaulting to ./TestCaseGenerator.js from config.js
Found property init() from module ./TestCaseGenerator.js
Successfully required module ./TestCaseGenerator.js
We have 1 modules available.
Server listening port 1000
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn chromium ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Comment: what have you done to try and resolve this? what commands were you running when you go the error? We need more details and context.

Answer (score 1):

I have been googling and I found someone who had a problem somewhat like mine. I think my problem may have to do with chromium. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018544/imagemagick-enoent-error . I'm not sure what to do at this point but at least I think I know where the problem is. The command I was using to run nodefuzz is sudo node nodefuzz.js
I am using a Mac running OSX Yosemite 10.10.4. Looking at other posts online I'm going to say that Nodefuzz can't find chromium. If that is the problem I'm not sure how to solve that issue.

Comment: It looks like you registered 2 accounts. Can we assume that you are the OP?

Comment: I am the op. I created this thread and the first post.

Comment: Please use the same accounts ....

Comment: Please edit your question with these new facts using your "greg" account

Comment: I lost the password to my email address linked to that account so I can't reset the password.

Comment: I'm still stuck. I have been googling for a while now and I still don't have a solution to this problem.